# Права доступа extjs

Tags: extjs

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с задачей добавления прав доступа ко views extjs. На уме только один вариант загружать json типа:

{
    view1: 1,
    view2: 0,
    view3: 0
}

Где 1 - write, 0 - read. И каждому view передавать параметром свой access. И уже в initComponent ставить условие включать тот или иной элемент во view или нет. Есть более красивые варианты? Может кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной задачей?

Comment: Интересная задача...  
Если решили, пожалуйста отпишитесь...  
Если не решили, то я присоединяюсь к вопросу!

Answer (score 3):

Раз стоит задача, что каждый `view` может принимать разные вариации в зависимости от прав доступа к нему, то да — "разруливать" эти вариации следует в `initComponent`. Вот только информацию о правах доступа я бы передавал не параметрами, а реализовал бы глобально доступный метод (через синглтон), который бы принимал аргументом имя `view` (и ещё, может быть, его контекст) и давал бы ответы `"read"`, `"write"`, `"none"` и т.п. Каждый `view` в своём `initComponent` опрашивал бы этот метод и получал бы ответ о том, как ему самого себя представить юзеру.

Такой подход позволит реализовать любую кастомную логику выдачи ответов `"read"`, `"write"`, `"none"` по имени `view`, и по умолчанию можно как раз настроить эту логику на опрос JSON из вашего примера, который в свою очередь придёт с сервера.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, есть более правильные и тривиальные решения, но в нашей конторе это реализовано следующим образом.
Авторизация в системе у нас проходит без участия ExtJS (4.2), потому что стандартные компоненты не позволяют работать функционалу автосохранения пароля в браузере. После авторизации, на странице мы создаем некий DOM элемент со статичным ID, в котором храним массив переменных с уровнем доступа, чтобы каждый раз не запрашивать их (в массиве более 500 значений). Для доступа к данным используем `Ext.get('element_id')`.

В `initComponent` и уже прогруженных `View` мы или дизейблим элементы, или вовсе их не рендерим. Но на стороне API всегда сохраняется проверка прав доступа.